# UE4: Take a given camera's view frustum and returns six planes that form it

Tags: unreal-engine4

I have an orthographic camera and I'd like to create a plane along its top, bottom, left and right edges but in Unreal Engine 4 there is no obvious way of getting the locations in world space, all I could get is the far and near clipping plane and that's not very helpful.

Unity3D has [an utility function](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes.html) that creates a plane for each frustum but I haven't found its implementation to see how it works.

Here's the camera I'm currently using and it's frustums in magenta.
[image]

Comment: what about `GetComponentLocation`?

Comment: Oooh, that's a good idea. Get component location, then combine that with the camera width/2 to get left and right side and use aspect ratio to get top and bottom. That might just work! Thank you :D

Comment: Yep, that worked. I'll post a full solution soon-ish! Thank you @ViniyoShouta

Comment: haha the funny thing is, I've never ever touched UE4 or any code related to it, all I did was google how to get an object position coordinates at a world, because I thought that there `MUST` be a way to getting locations on a world space directly...

Comment: A fresh perspective is always good :D I was digging so deep in the documentation that I forgot to look for more obvious solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a custom blueprint node for that returns the world coordinates for the centers of the top, left, bottom and right frustum planes.

To test it I've made it so that at game start a fire particle is initiated at the center of each of the planes. The cube represents the camera position.

[image: Before pressing play]

[image: After pressing play]

Blueprint usage

[image: Blueprint usage]

CameraUtils.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Camera/CameraActor.h"
#include "CameraUtils.generated.h"

/**
 * 
 */
UCLASS()
class PROJECTNAME_API ACameraUtils : public ACameraActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()


public:

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintPure,
        meta = (
            DisplayName = "Get Camera Edges from Frustum",
            Keywords = "Camera Edges Frustum"
            ),
        Category = "Camera|Utility")
        static void GetCameraFrustumEdges(UCameraComponent* camera, FVector& topCenter, FVector& leftCenter, FVector& bottomCenter, FVector& rightCenter);


};
```

CameraUtils.cpp

```
#include "ProjectName.h"
#include "CameraUtils.h"


void ACameraUtils::GetCameraFrustumEdges(UCameraComponent* camera, FVector& topCenter, FVector& leftCenter, FVector& bottomCenter, FVector& rightCenter)
{
    // Assumptions: Camera is orthographic, Z axis is upwards, Y axis is right, X is forward

    FMinimalViewInfo cameraView;
    camera->GetCameraView(0.0f, cameraView);

    float width = cameraView.OrthoWidth;
    float height = width / cameraView.AspectRatio;

    topCenter.Set(cameraView.Location.X,
                  cameraView.Location.Y,
                  cameraView.Location.Z + height/2.0f);

    bottomCenter.Set(cameraView.Location.X,
                     cameraView.Location.Y,
                     cameraView.Location.Z - height / 2.0f);

    leftCenter.Set(cameraView.Location.X,
                   cameraView.Location.Y - width / 2.0f,
                   cameraView.Location.Z);

    rightCenter.Set(cameraView.Location.X,
                    cameraView.Location.Y + width / 2.0f,
                    cameraView.Location.Z);

}
```